# SVN multiple repositories in subfolders

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, repository

I'm using apache+svn

apache config file:

```
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<Location /code>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath "c:/repositories"
</Location>
```

Imagine i have this file structure (in every t? i have one svn repository)

```
c
    repositories
        uc1
            0809v
                t1
                t2
                t3
            0809i
                t1
                t2
        uc2
            t1
            t2
        t1
```

I can access the repositories using:

```
svn://domain.com/code/uc1/0809v/t1  
svn://domain.com/code/uc1/0809v/t2  
svn://domain.com/code/uc1/0809v/t3
```

I want to access them using the urls:

```
http://domain.com/code/uc1/0809v/t1  
http://domain.com/code/uc1/0809v/t2  
http://domain.com/code/uc1/0809v/t3
```

and see the content of the repository in the browser.

If i create the repository on the root of the svn folder i can see the repository (http://domain.com/code/t1) when i try the other urls i get the error **Could not open the requested SVN filesystem**

My question is,
It is possible to do a search in all subfolders looking for svn repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) states that the directories under SVNParentPath have to be repositories, so no looking through all subdirectories.

You might be able to make script though, that would output several Location-blocks matching the parent folders of SVN repositories.

Comment: That means that i have to restart apache every time i create a new repository !?  


Thank you! 

My bad to not lookup documentation -.-

Comment: I believe reloading configuration is needed, not restarting apache.

Comment: To reload the configurations you need to restart. Right?

Comment: Well, graceful restart is called a restart, but I think of it more like reloading configuration as the parent process isn't really restarted. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html#graceful

Answer (score 0):

Some time back, I got multiple repositories setup under root in VisualSVN server, now I got to backup these multiple repositories.

I can use svnadmin dump to backup at root level, how to backup the multiple repositories under root.